# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos de Firebase desde un Listview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

La pantalla de mi aplicación tras logearse cuenta con el siguiente diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de cada medicamento creado (nombre y dosis) se muestran sin ningún tipo de problema en el ListView gracias al adapter adaptado a la clase Medicamento que he creado. El problema es el siguiente: estoy tratando de añadir un ImageButton a cada objeto del ListView que permita al pinchar en él eliminar el objeto Medicamento concreto elegido, de tal forma que sus datos no se vean más en el ListView.

Este es el código del adaptador:

```
class MedicinaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicina> {

        Context context;
        List<Medicina> medicinas;

        public MedicinaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,
                              @NonNull List<Medicina> medicinas) {
            super(context, resource, medicinas);
            this.context=context;
            this.medicinas=medicinas;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            //Para el objeto i-ésimo recupero el elemento de la lista contenedora
            final Medicina medicina=medicinas.get(i);
            //Recupero el "inflador" de layouts
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater().from(context);
            //Inflo el layout item_message que he definido
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicina,viewGroup,false);

            //Recupero los componentes del item_message
            TextView nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoNombre);
            TextView dosis=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoDosis);
            //Inicializamos ImageViews
            ImageButton mEditView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoEditMedicina);
            ImageButton mDeleteView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

            //A cada imagen le asociamos una función: en este caso, a uno la función de editar y a otro la de borrar de firebase
            mDeleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //aquí tendría que poner para que se elimine el //medicamento seleccionado
                }
            });







            //Le asigno los valores del mensaje
            nombre.setText(medicina.getNombre());
            dosis.setText(medicina.getDosis());

            //Devuelvo la vista que he creado
            return view;
        }
    }
```

¿Qué podría hacer para eliminar el medicamento? No estoy pidiendo una solución hecha, sino simplemente agradecería una orientación para seguir resolviendo el problema.

En la base de datos el objeto Medicamento se ve de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que estás en el método `getView` del adaptador, que es llamado cuando se va a mostrar cada una de las líneas de tu lista. Y ahí quieres poner un listener para eliminar el mismo elemento que estás pintando. Se me ocurre que igual era mejor poner un listener a la lista, cuando por ejemplo te quedas pulsando largo sobre un elemento. Eso lo harías en la Activity donde muestras la lista, no en el adaptador. Y ahí accederías al adaptador, eliminarías el elemento de la lista del adaptador, lo eliminarias de Firebase y llamarías a `notifyDataSetChanged` para repintar la lista.

Comment: @SuperG280 Supongamos que hago que se elimine el objeto cuando se pulse sobre el ImageButton delete que aparece en cada línea del ListView. ¿Tendría que seguir inicializándolo dentro del adapter? ¿O inicializarlo fuera del mismo?

Comment: El problema es que la función `getView` en la que has puesto el listener del `ImageButton`, retorna un `View`, concretamente el elemento de la línea de la lista. Se llama a `getView` una vez por cada línea. Y el listener está en esa función. Se supone que cuando borras el elemento tienes que repintar la lista entera, por eso te proponía poner el listener fuera del adapter, asociado a la lista entera, no a un `ImageButton` en cada línea. Prueba a ver qué pasa si ahí donde tienes el listener, eliminas el elemento de tu lista y ejecutas `notifyDataSetChanged`. Pero no se si esto se puede hacer.